# Is there a sensor to measure a distance between 2 point as in range [0-2 meter]?

Tags: sensors

I'm looking for a way of detecting if 2 pieces of hardware are within 2 meters of eachother or not. The idea is to build a prototype to lock computers automatically. I just need a recommendation on the sensor if it exists. Geofencing, bluetooth etc are not reliable enough.

Comment: Just point a ultrasonic sensor towards the chair in front of the PC. Or add a force sensor to the chair.

Comment: i would try an ultrasonic emitter for the wrist, like those "mosquito repelling" things, along with a sensitive mic on the other end. Audio fades very reliably at distance; twice as far is 25% as loud, and the dead-simple "buzzer" can be very low power compared to more complicated emitters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot of different methods with advantages/disadvantages:

- Use an IR LED/receiver and calculate the distance of travelling of the lights. Disadvantage: you need a very precise timing mechanism (light is fast), also take latency into account for non-light parts, and hardware needs to be in visible range and pointing to each other with LEDs)
- Use an ultrasonic sensor like SR-HC04. Disadvantage: devices must point to each other in a small precise angle.
- Using an RF method and sending/receiving e.g. via nRF24L01+ 2.4 GHz trasnceivers, to check the difference in time between sending and receiving when very close or a few meters apart. However, there might be aspects that might distort the result (other receivers/transmitters, what kind of material is in between, nRF antenna placement/direction etc). Using lowest speed (most reliable), highest power.

Comment: I was thinking more of a bracelet like design, which will not work with both of these sensors. What are they using in these ankle bracelets for criminals? ;)

Comment: "What are they using in these ankle bracelets for criminals?" GPS

Comment: I doubt they will use GPS, since you don't have GPS in house and you can cover/circumvent GPS signals easily. So my bet is a signal that is sent and received and a time difference (travel) time is performed calculating distance.

Comment: no need to monitor a position of the bracelet in the house

Comment: It seems you are partly right, GPS + other mechanisms (sending to fixed location): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankle_monitor   ... however, a device at a fixed location does not really help answering the question itself.

Comment: Yes to specify: I try to solve the "user forgets to lock the computer" problem with a hardware prototype. For fun.

Comment: I would do some tests starting with nRF24L01+ 2.4 GHz (if you have them) and check if you notice a difference in sending time and receiving time when very close or a few meters apart. However, there might be aspects that might distort the result (other receivers/transmitters, what kind of material is in between, nRF antenna placement/direction etc). Using lowest speed (most reliable), highest power.